# how to perform orderby in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

Hi i have the following table

```
cod     desc            date
131     test1           
132     test2
133     test3
134     test4
133     test3           20180301
133     test3           20180308
131     test1           20180227
134     test4           20180305
134     test4           20180225
132     test2           20180130
```

i should select the rows with empty date ordered by the date desc
in other word the result should be like that :

```
cod     desc            date
133     test3
134     test4
131     test1
132     test2
```

[**sqlfiddle link**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9e8e0/23)

the query i performed is

```
with test as (
  select t1.cod, t1.desc, t1.date
  from mytable t1 
  )
 select cod, desc, date 
 from test where date =''
 order by test.date desc
```

but the result is not what i intended

```
cod     desc            date
131     test1   
132     test2   
133     test3   
134     test4
```

for me it seems it doesn't use the (order by) correctly.

the real problem is
it's medicine items when the doctor write it for the first time he doesn't register the date, and when the nurse give it to the patient then it's register the date so, my problem is to show the recent medicine which in my case the item with empty date ordered by the recent date

i will appreciate any guideline where i did the mistake

Comment: Do you store dates as strings?

Comment: yes, as you can see in the following link 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9e8e0/23

Comment: How would you expect '' to sort?  That CTE is just the table.  How does that CTE add value?

Comment: You say it should be ordered by 'date desc' but have not shown / included what that is, the query is about when date is specifically empty so what exactly are you wanting to sort by? 4 empty blanks and expect a specific order from blank values?

Comment: You should add a new criteria to sort when date = ''

Comment: i tried to change the order by to the following 
order by case when date = '' then test.date end desc

Comment: from the main table i should get the result 
133     test3
134     test4
131     test1
132     test2
i searched here and googled till i though about this solution

Comment: @M.A.Hassan - you have not explained why ordering on a blank value has a specific order in your expected results above. Dates stored in a varchar is going to give you so many headaches, if you can change it - you really should.

Comment: @Andrew it's medicine items when the doctor write it for the first time he doesn't register the date, and when the nurse give it to the patient then it's register the date so, my problem is to show the recent medicine which in my case the item with empty date ordered by the recent date

Comment: @M.A.Hassan - that's the kind of explanation you need to edit into the question - it might seem obvious to you as the question writer, but for people trying to help its not obvious and we can't read minds sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't exclude the empty dates, use an aggregation instead to find the maximum date:

```
select cod, desc, max(date)
from test 
group by cod, desc
order by max(date) desc
```

If you don't want to show the date, most DBMSes support ordering by a column which is not in the Select list:

```
select cod, desc
from test 
group by cod, desc
order by max(date) desc
```

Depending on how your DBMS sorts NULLs, you might need to add an option lke

```
order by max(date) desc NULLS LAST
```

See your [modified fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9e8e0/90)

Comment: the problem is: this should be a table of medicine where the doctor insert the prescription medicine and for the first time i don't register the date, after that the nurse give the medicine to the patient and in this case i insert the same item but with date, furthermore when the nurse gonna give the patient  the same prescription i want to order what the doctor wrote in the first time with empty date and then use the recent date of prescription made by the nurse

Comment: @M.A.Hassan:There's no *first time with empty date* in a DBMS unless you keep a timestamp indicating this, i.e. the order of rows doesn't neccessarily represent the order of inserts. Currently there's no way to get your data returned by the order of inserts and showing the most recent date.

Comment: @M.A.Hassan: Btw, did you try my query? It matches your desired result. If you don't want to return a medicine which was prescribed, but never given you can add `HAVING max(date) > ''`

Comment: @dneoth thanks a lot for your effort, i tried your query but is still not matching my desired result since, i just want to get the records with empty dates only ordered by the dates of the other records as shown in the description of the question.

Comment: @M.A.Hassan: Well, the fiddle result is exactly the order you expected in your description.

Answer (score 0):

This begs the question of which date you want to use, when `cod` appears multiple times.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from test t
where t.date = ''  -- don't store dates as strings
order by (select max(t2.date) from test t2 where t2.cod = t.cod);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply order by clause on an empty field!!. Is this what you are after? [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9e8e0/63)

```
with test as (
  select t1.cod, t1.desc, t1.date
  from mytable t1 
  )
 select t.cod, t.desc, t.date 
 from test as t
 inner join (
     select cod
     from test where date =''
         group by cod
 )  sel
 on t.cod = sel.cod
 where t.date <> ''
 order by t.date desc
```

Comment: the problem is it's medicine items when the doctor write it for the first time he doesn't register the date, and when the nurse give it to the patient then it's register the date so, my problem is to show the recent medicine which in my case the item with empty date ordered by the recent date

Comment: Try this one 
```
 with test as (
  select t1.cod, t1.desc, t1.date
  from mytable t1 
  )
 select t.cod, t.desc, t.date 
 from test as t
 inner join (
         select cod
 ( -- select cod with latest date from nurse
   select cod,
   row_number() over(cod order by date desc) as rnk
   from test where date <> '' 
         ) ranked
        where rnk = 1
 )  sel
 on t.cod = sel.cod
-- select records from doctor where there is no date
 where t.date = '' 
```

Comment: step1: The inner query selects all records with a valid date and ranks them based on the desc order of date. This is sub query ranked.
step2: Get the cod with rank 1. This would be the record with latest date. This is subquery sel.
step3: Use the cod from sub query sel to get to the records to be selected from outer query with where clause date = '' that is records without date.